# Thinksboard - Authentication in API rest call failing

Tags: rest, authentication, access-token, thingsboard

I have to use thingsboard by rest API as it is showed on the guide https://thingsboard.io/docs/reference/rest-api/
In particular, I have a live-demo server and a custom user with administration permission.
I can authenticate it with the username/password on the thingsboard interface 
Unfortunately, when I try the following command 
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d '{"username":, "password":}' 'https://THINGSBOARD_URL/api/auth/login'

I receive the following output:
{"status":401,"message":"Authentication failed","errorCode":10,"timestamp":"..."}

Anybody can help me? 
I will glad,

Gianluca

Answer (score 0):

Solved
It was certifciate problem,
I bypass it by the following command:
 tokenAuthResp = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=loginJSON, verify=False).json()